# Upper bound for $\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{n-2}{i}}{\sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{n}{i}}$

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics

How to simplify $P = \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{n-2}{i}}{\sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{n}{i}}$ to get an upper bound in terms of $n$ and $k$. Here $k \le n$ and $\binom{n}{r}$ is the binomial coefficient that denotes the number of ways to choose $r$ objects from a set of $n$ objects.

$P$ is the probability that 2 fixed objects $u,v \in S$ where $S$ is a set of $n$ distinct objects, are both not present in a random subset $C$ of $S$ where $|C| \le k$ so trivially $P \le 1$

Interpretation:

Numerator = Number of subsets of size $\le k$ without $u,v$

Denominator = All possible subsets with size $\le k$

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28+sum+%28%28n-2%29+choose+i%29,+i%3D0+to+k+%29+%2F+%28sum+%28n+choose+i%29,+i%3D0+to+k%29

Comment: @BanachTarski Try this Wolfram Alpha link above. Seems like a complex expression, your function I mean.

Comment: Yes I did see that before posting here and its complexity is what drove me to ask here for a more workable form :P

Comment: @Travis Yes. Normal approximation will be good only if $k=n/2+O(n^{1/2})$ (or something like that).

Comment: For large $n$, (1) the occurrences of $u, v$ in the subset are nearly independent, and (2) the vast majority of subsets of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ have $\approx \frac{n}{2}$ elements (in a sense that can be formalized). So for any $\epsilon > 0$, one naively expects in the regime where $\frac{k}{n} > \frac{1}{2} + \epsilon$, the probability that a randomly selected subset of $k \leq n$ elements excludes both $u$ and $v$ tends to $\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^2 = \tfrac{1}{4}$ as $n$ gets large.

Answer (score -1):

Let $F_n$ and $f_n$ be respectively CDF and pmf of $B(n,\frac 1 2)$. Then $$P=\frac 1 4\frac {F_{n-2}(k)}{F_n(k)}=\frac 1 4\frac {F_{n-2}(k)}{F_{n-2}(k)-\frac 3 4f_{n-2}(k)-\frac 1 4f_{n-2}(k-1)}$$ From CLT we get that for $k\ge \frac n 2-O(n^{\frac 1 2})$ $$P= \frac 1 4+O(n^{-\frac 1 2})\tag 1$$
For $k=o(n)$, we easily get $P\to 1$
and if $k= an$ for $0<a<\frac 1 2$, let $r=\frac{a}{1-a}$ [to get](http://anothersample.net/tutorial-on-large-deviations-for-the-binomial-distribution) $$P\to \frac 1 {(1+r)^2}=(1-a)^2\tag 2$$

which agrees with the other two regimes. This result is very easy to explain - when $k=an<\frac n 2$, most of the sets in consideration are very close in size to $k$ and chances that two elements don't belong to a specific such set are $(1-a)^2$.